# Passing string and block do in ruby method

Tags: ruby

Trying to pass a block in the method:

```
self.handler_method("pinterest", do |pinterest|
   handle_facebook(pinterest.get_facebook[:username]) if pinterest.facebook_found?
   handle_twitter(pinterest.get_twitter[:username]) if pinterest.twitter_found?
end).call(username)
```

Which keeps returning error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block (SyntaxError)
                self.handler_method "pinterest", do |pinterest|
                                                   ^
```

How can I fix it such that it accepts both arguments. I can do the inline block way `{}` but would rather the expanded with `do, end`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
self.handler_method("pinterest") do |pinterest|
   handle_facebook(pinterest.get_facebook[:username]) if pinterest.facebook_found?
   handle_twitter(pinterest.get_twitter[:username]) if pinterest.twitter_found?
end.call(username)
```

Comment: That is correct! Waiting for the 12mins. But why does that work and not within the method parenthesis

Comment: Because block to method should be passed outside them.

Comment: From the caller's perspective, the block is not a method argument. You only put method args in parenthesis (if at all in Ruby). `do … end` then always follows the arguments without them. I'm saying "from the caller's perspective" because when implementing a method that takes a block, you might specify the block as an argument in the method signature. That's one of Ruby's inconsistencies...